# Is it possible to get the size of the item the pointer is pointing at?

Tags: c

Is it possible to find the size of item_t through the pointer?

```
typedef struct item
{
  char x;
  char y;
  char life;
}item_t;

void main (void)
{
  item_t test;
  void *ptr = &test;
  printf("%d\n",sizeof(ptr));
}
return: 8
```

Comment: it returns 8 because you are running a 64 bit platform, void pointers aren't useful for getting, instead try sizeof(item_t);

Comment: Short answer: *no*. Given only `ptr`, all you have is an address.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Short answer: Yes (with some caveats). Oh, never mind, I didn't notice that it's a `void*`. I'll fix my answer.

Comment: I understand why it returns 8, but I am wondering if theres a way for me to use the pointer in convergence with sizeof to find the size of what it's pointing at. edit: I have simplified the question and sizeof(item_t) wont help me out. Thanks for the response though ;-)

Comment: What you try here is actually a bit like telling the pointer "we don't know what you're pointing at" and then ask in the next question "so tell me how large is that, then?"

Answer (score 3):

Not if `ptr` is of type `void*` -- but it probably shouldn't be.

You can't dereference a `void*` pointer. You can convert it to some other pointer type and dereference the result of the conversion. That can sometimes be useful, but more often you should just define the pointer with the correct type in the first place.

If you want a pointer to an `item_t` object, use an `item_t*` pointer:

```
item_t test;
item_t *ptr = &test;
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(*ptr));
```

This will give you the size of a single `item_t` object, because that's the type that `ptr` points to. If `ptr` is uninitialized, or is a null pointer, you'll get the same result, because the operand of `sizeof` is  not evaluated (with one exception that doesn't apply here). If `ptr` was initialized to point to the initial element of an *array* of `item_t` objects:

```
ptr = malloc(42 * sizeof *ptr);
```

`sizeof *ptr` will still only give you the size of one of them.

The `sizeof` operator is (usually) evaluated at compile time. It uses only information that's available to the compiler. No run-time calculation is performed. (The exception is an operand whose type is a variable-length array.)

The correct format for printing a value of type `size_t` (such as the result of `sizeof`) is `%zu`, not `%d`.

And `void main(void)` should be `int main(void)` (unless you have a very good reason to use a non-standard definition -- which you almost certainly don't). If a book told you to define `main` with a return type of `void`, get a better book; its author doesn't know C very well.

Comment: @chux: Right, I didn't initially notice that `ptr` was of type `void*`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The reason main is void is because i take some shortcuts when I'm using an empty file to try out some code. I do appriciate the response though ;-)

Comment: @MortenBertheussen: How is that a shortcut? `int` is shorter than `void` (and in C99 or later, you don't need `return 0;` at the end of `main`).

Comment: What can i say? I did not know that in C99 or late you didn't have to return 0. ;-)

Comment: Detail: `sizeof *ptr` fails in at least 3 situations 1) `void*`, `some_function*` and a pointer to a yet-to-be defined `struct/union`.

Comment: @MortenBertheussen: In C99 and later, reaching the closing `}` of `main` (assuming it was defined to return a result of type `int`) does an implicit `return 0;`.

Comment: @chux: 4) `ptr` is a pointer to an incomplete array type. (Cases 1, 3 and 4 can be summarized as a pointer to an incomplete type.) And just for completeness: 5) `ptr` is not a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no. Given only ptr, all you have is an address (answer by WhozCraig).

Longer answer: you can implement [inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming)) by having the first field in all your structs specify its size. For example:

```
struct something_that_has_size
{
  size_t size;
};

struct item
{
  size_t size;
  char x;
  char y;
  char life;
};

struct item2
{
  size_t size;
  char x;
  char y;
  char z;
  char life;
};

// Somewhere in your code
...
struct item *i1 = malloc(sizeof(struct item));
i1->size = sizeof(struct item); // you are telling yourself what the size is
struct item2 *i2 = malloc(sizeof(struct item2));
i2->size = sizeof(struct item2);

// Later in your code
void *ptr = ... // get a pointer somehow
size_t size = ((struct something_that_has_size*)ptr)->size; // here is your size
```

But instead of size, you should better record the *type* of your `struct` - it's more useful than just the size. This technique is called [discriminated union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I see now that i need to construct my program a little differently.

Comment: Upticked. This method, if the conditions allow it, is very common. It is used extensively in industry. Microsoft, for example, does this is *many* places. It is not-coincidentally also used for detecting different *versions* of some structures.

Comment: Certainly you want a `*` in `struct item i1 = malloc(sizeof(item));`  (code assigned a pointer to a structure).  Suggest `struct item *i1 = malloc(sizeof *i1);`

Comment: Bug fixed. I prefer `sizeof(struct item)` but `sizeof *i1` is equivalent and might be better, depending on your style.

Answer (score 1):

You can only cast a `void` pointer to get what is behind in the correct type, you cannot dereference it directly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct item {
  char x;
  char y;
  char life;
} item_t;

int main()
{
  item_t test;
  void *ptr = &test;
  printf("%zu %zu\n", sizeof(*(item_t *) ptr), sizeof(item_t));
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);;
}
```

But that is of not much use because you need to know the type in the first place and have won nothing.

TL;DR: no, not possible

Comment: Thanks for the help. I see now that i need to construct my program a little differently.